# Mysql - Multi selection with a single query

Tags: mysql, arrays, join

I have a table that holds events. The front-end displays all the events as cards. One event, one card. I also have a table that holds subscriptions. One event, many subscriptions.

Is there a way to retrieve all the events with all their subscriptions with a single query?

Currently, I do a query to get all the events, then I run a loop and run a query for each events to fetch its subscriptions. So, as the number of events increase, the number of sub-queries (and db connections) increase. That's why I'd like to know if it's possible to reduce this to a single query.

```
event                     subscription
+----------+              +------------+
id                        id
name                      user
location                  age
date                      event_id
```

### ...                       ...

TRYING TO MAKE MY QUESTION EASIER :P

To simplify it, think about a Facebook post. Facebook shows the post and all the users that have liked it, right? So, is there a way to bring all the posts and all the usernames that have liked each post, in a single query?

Comment: If you're looking for a simple join, then GMB has a solution, or are you trying to make it so that there is only one event row with all the subscription data, then that would be a different setup.

Comment: To confirm the answer below, is there an `event_id` in your subscription table?

Comment: @Ibu yes, there is.

Comment: How you plan to display the results can make a big difference.

Comment: Simple example: I have Event A and Event B. The Event A has 2 Subscriptions. The Event B has 3 Subscriptions. I want a query that will bring me all the Events and all the Subscriptions for each Event. Then, I will display like:
`Event A => 1st subscription data => 2nd subscription data`
`Event B => 1st subscription data => 2nd subscription data => 3rd subscription data`

Comment: you could try to use a GROUP_CONCAT but honestly it might be worth it to just do a bit of processing server-side before sending the data.

Comment: I updated the question trying to make myself clearer

Comment: RE: your edit, then that sounds like it could be done by a group concat, so long as you're grabbing only a small bit of info from the subscriptions. Otherwise it might be easier to just grab the total count, and then in your UI have it request other data when necessary (like how facebook grabs comments on long threads)

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, so

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for a simple `JOIN`. Assuming that column `event_id` in table `subscription` maps to the `id` of the `event`, that would look like:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.location, e.date, s.id, s.user, s.age
FROM event e
INNER JOIN subscription s ON s.event_id = e.id
```

Comment: isn't it for a JOIN between tables with one-to-one relationship?

Comment: No, Joins can have a one-to-many relationship. `INNER JOIN` is just stating that you expect for there to be a relationship between the events and the subscriptions. If there could theoretically be an even without a subscription, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: I updated the question trying to make myself clearer

Comment: @RodrigoOlivares: as far as concerns, this query will do what you expect. I suggest that you test it agains your actual data and let us knowwhether the results that you get do match your expectations.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks!